# HTML Dynamic/Responsive Element Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am creating a web app in ASP.NET. The page uses a Master and has only two things
1. GridView at the bottom
2. A DIV at the top that i will develop further

The idea was to have the top div or header fixed/freezed so that when user scrolls down the top portion holds its position or in other words always floats at the top

This is what i have so far

```
    <div class='fixed header'>

</div>

<%--<div class='fixed side'></div>--%>

<div class='scrollable'>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RecordID" DataSourceID="History">
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scrollable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    position:relative;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.header{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  top:auto;
}

.side {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}


.controlPanel{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

But grid overlaps the top div if i resize the window.

I need the grid to always show under the top white block.

I know i can add top or margin but that may not auto-adjust to the div dimensions.

This is where i need help.

Comment: Your margin is in percentage. Try using a fixed value.

Comment: the top div resizes on resizing the window, will changing the margin from % to fixed value work in that case?

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything just correct your **.header** css class to

```
.header
 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
 }
```